# Defining variables for use in both Makefiles and Shell scripts

Tags: bash, variables, makefile

I'd like to distribute a set of build variables (which someone should append to their LDFLAGS), in a form that can both be included in a Makefile and in a shell script.

What I have now is a file buildflags.conf:

```
LDFLAGS_EXTRA="-static -foo -bar"
```

I want my users to be able to, when they're using makefiles:

```
include buildflags.conf
LDFLAGS+=$LDFLAGS_EXTRA
```

Or, when they're using a shell script, do something like:

```
. buildflags.conf
gcc myapp.o -o myapp $LDFLAGS_EXTRA
```

This doesn't work however, since bash needs quotes around my LDFLAGS_EXTRA definition, while make does not want them.

Anyone with a solution for this? I don't want to maintain multiple separate buildflags files, although a set of scripts that start from a single definition file and make it suitable for inclusion in different contexts would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the easiest solution is to just include the shell script containing the variable definitions in your make recipes (this works fine if your recipes are simple):

```
target: sources
    . buildflags.conf ; \
    gcc -o $@ $^ $$LDFLAGS_EXTRA
```

Note the extra `$` in the variable usage and the fact that the two lines are in fact one statement, the `;\` is important.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good idea. I suspect that most users will use makefiles though, so I'd rather have the extra burden on the shell scripts. Is there any way of having make export its variables to a shell script?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a different shell script that reads the configuration?  If so, just do something like `eval \`awk -F= '{ printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2 }' < buildflags.conf \``

Comment: Perfect! I had solved it in the meantime by building separate versions in my packaging script, using an `awk` command similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Ivo's solution in his comment has brought me to another one that works as well and is more canonical for Makefiles:

1) Define `LDFLAGS_EXTRA` as in the question

2) Post process the list for use in Makefiles

```
LDFLAGS_EXTRA_POST=$(subst ",,${LDFLAGS_EXTRA})
```

3) Make sure to only reference `LDFLAGS_EXTRA_POST` in Makefiles